# Must a call to pthread_cond_wait be woken up by pthread_cond_signal?

Tags: c, pthreads

The title basically speaks for itself.  If I make a call to pthread_cond_wait with a particular condition and mutex, will that thread stay blocked until a call to pthread_cond_signal is made with the corresponding condition?  Or will it unblock regardless if the mutex is subsequently unlocked again?

If the answer is the former, I have a follow-up.  I have a queue used for message-passing between my threads.  I want to ensure only one thread can append an item to the queue at a time (hence the use of mutexes).  None of the threads have any idea if any other thread will be waiting to take hold of the mutex themselves.

When attempting to append an item to the queue, I lock the mutex, wait for the queue to not be full with a pthread condition, then perform the append, then unlock the mutex.  Before unlocking it, should I perform a pthread_cond_signal, even if I don't know whether or not any other threads will be waiting?  What happens if multiple threads are waiting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Someone needs to signal/broadcast the condition variable, otherwise waiting threads don't *necessarily* get woken up. You can also get "spurious" wake-ups, but don't rely on them. Once a waiter has been woken (by a signal or broadcast or spuriously), it will start trying to acquire the mutex, and once it has *that* `pthread_cond_wait` returns.
2. If there are multiple threads waiting then one of them is woken (arbitrarily or according to rules documented by the implementation). In your code as you describe it, the only place a thread ever waits on this condvar is when it's trying to add an item to a full queue. So you have three options:

   - signal the condition variable each time you *remove* an element from a full queue. This wakes one of the 0 or more waiters. Then signal again after it adds an element, if the queue is still not full, just in case there was more than 1 waiter.
   - broadcast the condition variable each time you remove an element from a full queue. Now you don't need to signal after adding an element.
   - signal the condition variable each time you remove an element, regardless of whether the queue is full or not. If you do this, don't make the mistake of changing the code in future to remove two elements in one go and only signal once. Condition variables reduce the number of waiters by one each time you signal, and this approach works because it prevents there ever simultaneously being at least one waiter, *and* fewer woken ex-waiters trying to acquire the mutex than there are spaces in the queue. So you never get threads waiting when there's a space they could use.

The way to think of this is that the "condition" you're waiting for is, "the queue is not full". Whenever the condition *becomes* true, you should signal or broadcast the condition variable. If you choose to signal, and there might be multiple waiters, then each waiter needs to signal (to wake the next waiter) if the condition *remains* true after it has done its thing.

If you don't care about the performance cost of a few extra context switches, and provided you have written the code that waits on the condvar correctly to cope with spurious wakes, it is also safe to signal or broadcast a condvar when the condition is still false. This is one of the nice things about condition variables, it makes it easier to reason about the correctness of the code. So the requirement "whenever the condition becomes true, you should signal or broadcast the condition variable" means only what it says. You don't have to signal if *and only if* the condition becomes true.

So in this case it would be fine to signal each time you remove an element from the queue, regardless of whether or not it was full beforehand. In this case it's easy to cut down the number of signals to the minimum necessary, but occasionally it is more trouble than it is worth to work out for sure whether the condition has become true, so instead you signal if it's now true and *might* have been false before, or even just signal if it *might* be true now. I wouldn't advise putting in extra wakes for no reason, but sometimes it makes the code simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Thw `pthread_cond_wait` call will unblock once both a) the condition variable is signalled and b) the other thread has unlocked the mutex. Then `pthread_cond_wait` will lock the mutex and return.

(Note that you almost always need to re-check your real test, such as "Is the queue full?", after `pthread_cond_wait` returns. Typically you'd call it in a `while` loop for that reason.)

You can't check whether any other threads are waiting on the condition variable using pthread APIs, so the normal pattern would be to call either `pthread_cond_signal` or `pthread_cond_broadcast` before you unlock the mutex. These are cheap if nobody is waiting.

The difference between "signal" and "broadcast" is the former only wakes up one waiting thread (and it's not specified which one), while the latter wakes up all of them.

I think in your case, you should "broadcast" each time you remove an item from the queue, to let inserting threads know they have a shot. You then don't need to signal inserting threads from other inserts.

Answer (score 1):

When you put an item in the queue, signal the condition variable if the queue was previously empty - that way you wake up a thread that might wait to fetch an item from the queue. If the queue was not empty, there's no reason for a fetching thread to block on the condition, so no need for a signal.

When you fetch an item from the queue, signal **another** condition variable if the queue was previous completely full - that way you wake up a thread that might wait to put an item in the queue. If the queue was not full, there's no reason for an appending thread to block on the condition, so no need for a signal.

Do not broadcast, unless you get/put more than one item from/to the queue. If you put just one item, resp. make available just one slot and you broadcast, you will wake up all the threads, but only one will be able to make progress, all others will go back to wait and waking them up, they resuming and going back to sleep will be a pure overhead.

Answer (score 0):

1 Yes. The mutex associated with the call to `pthread_cond_wait()` is unlocked by the function.

2 Any thread waiting on the condition may be resumed. When `pthread_cond_wait()` returns, the associated mutex is locked.

> pthread_cond_wait
>
> **atomically  unlocks the mutex** (as per pthread_unlock_mutex) and waits
>   for the condition variable cond to be signaled. The thread execution
>   is suspended and does not consume any CPU time until the condition
>          variable is signaled. The mutex must be locked by the calling thread on entrance to pthread_cond_wait. **Before returning to the
>   calling thread, pthread_cond_wait re-acquires mutex** (as per
>   pthread_lock_mutex).